# Proving 10 Properties of Vector Addition and Scalar Multiplication for Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

I am trying to write proofs for the following Properties of Vector Addition/Scalar Multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

> **Distributive  Property 1**: $c(\vec{u} + \vec{v}) =c\vec{u} + c\vec{v}$
>
> **Distributive Property 2**: $(c+d)\vec{u} = c\vec{u} + d\vec{u}$

I have this so far for **Distributive Property 1**:

$\begin{align}
c((u_{1}, u_{2} , ... , u_{n})  +(v_{1}, v_{2}, ... , v_{n})) && \text{Definition of Vectors in n-dimensions}\tag1\\
c(u_{1} + v_{1}, u_{2} + v_{2}, ... , u_{n} + v_{n}) && \text{Vector Addition}\tag2\\
(c(u_{1} + v_{1}), c(u_{2} + v_{2}), ... , c(u_{n} + v_{n})) && \text{Scalar Multiplication}\tag3\\
(cu_{1} + cv_{1}, cu_{2} + cv_{2}, ... , cu_{n} + cv_{n}) && \text{Distributive Property of } \mathbb{R}\tag4\\
(cu_{1}, cu_{2}, ... ,cu_{n}) +(cv_{1},cv_{2},...,cv_{n}) && \text{Vector Addition (Reverse)}\tag5\\
c(u_{1}, u_{2}, ... , cu_{n}) + c(v_{1}, v_{2},...,v_{n}) && \text{Scalar Multiplication (Reverse)}\tag6\\
\end{align}$

However, I am having trouble discerning the difference between Distributive Property of Real Numbers and Scalar Multiplication and knowing which one to use/cite in my proofs.

On line 3, I originally had **Distributive Property of Real Numbers** as opposed to **Scalar Multiplication**, but my professor corrected it to Scalar Multiplication.

Similarly, I have the same concerns for **Distributive Property 2**:

$\begin{align}
(c+d)(u_{1}, u_{2}, ... , u_{n}) && \text{Definition of Vectors in n-dimensions} \tag1\\
((c+d)u_{1}, (c+d)u_{2}, ... , (c+d)u_{n}) && \text{Scalar Multiplication}\tag2\\
((cu_{1} + du_{1}, cu_{2} + du_{2}, ... , cu_{n} + du_{n}) && \text{Scalar Multiplication}\tag3\\
(cu_{1}, cu_{2}, ... , cu_{n}) + (du_{1}, du_{2}, ... ,du_{n}) && \text{Vector Addition (Reverse)}\tag4\\
\end{align}$

I recall my professor saying about how it is due to the differences between whether or not the scalar is applied on real numbers and vectors; in this example, I can see how that would relate to line 2, as we are applying a scalar on a vector. However, given that $(c+d)$ is now applied to all the elements of the vector, would we not begin to use the distributive property on line 3?

Comment: You can't prove axioms. They are axioms.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify what I meant. I assumed it was interchangeable with axioms, apologies.

Comment: In the proof of first property, the correct logic sequence should be:

$$c(u_1 + v_1,\ldots) \stackrel{*1}{=} (c(u_1 + v_1),\ldots) \stackrel{*2}= (cu_1 + cv_1,\ldots)$$
*1 : definition of scalar multiplication of vectors. *2 : distributive properties of real numbers.

Comment: I think I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out!